# How to create a spinners that will download data from mysql?

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit, slim

I am trying to create a spinner that will download data from the database and will assign user roles. I created two tables: `users` and `roles`. In the users table, I have a column `"roles_idroles"` and want to add a role using the spinner, but not after the id, but after the name of the role that is in the `"roles"` table.

How do you download roles from another table?

```
public function createUser($First_Name, $Last_Name, $Email, $password, $roles_idroles){

       if(!$this->isEmailExist($Email)){

            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (First_Name,Last_Name, Email, password, roles_idroles) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $First_Name, $Last_Name, $Email, $password, $roles_idroles );

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return USER_CREATED; 
            }else{
                return USER_FAILURE;
            }
       }
       return USER_EXISTS; 
    }
```

And I need help creating it in android.

I would like to display the available user roles after pressing on the spinner and after the selection I can assign this role to the user when registering.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your table you have something like it:

```
users
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id | First_Name | Last_Name | Email | password | roles_idroles |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

roles
----------------------------
| roles_idroles | role_name |
----------------------------
```

you can do it in 3 steps
1° get the user info
2° get the roles_idroles associate to that user
3° get the role_name of that role by his id.

Lets go!!

```
$role_name="";
$role_id=0;
if($result != USER_FAILURE){
  $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT 'roles_idroles' FROM users WHERE Email='?'");
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$Email);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($user_role);
  while($stmt->fetch()){
    $role_id= $user_role;
  }
  $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT 'role_name' FROM roles WHERE 'roles_idroles'='?'");
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$role_id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($name);
  while($stmt->fetch()){
    $role_name= $name;
  }
}else{
  //something
}
echo "My Role is $role_name";
```

Also you can do something more fast using 'JOIN' to merge both tables and get the role_name directly.
[Here a example](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: I need to create new function and put this code there?

Comment: yes, you can do something like it:
`function GetRoleName($First_Name, $Last_Name, $Email, $password, $roles_idroles){

      $result = $this->createUser($First_Name, $Last_Name, $Email, $password, $roles_idroles);

       ... my code here ...

}`